# Django + nginx + gunicorn not being able to serve static files

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, nginx, gunicorn

I'm trying to deploy a django app in a EC2 instance but I'm currently having issues serving the static files of the app.

Currently, my nginx's conf file looks like this:

```
# Default server configuration
#
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8000;
        }


        location /static/ {
                #autoindex on;
                root /home/ubuntu/some/folder/static/;
        }
}
```

Also in my settings.py file in my django project I have the following config related to my static files:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/ubuntu/some/folder/static/'
```

and Gunicorn, I'm launching it as the following:

```
gunicorn3 --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 myproject.wsgi:application
```

And with that, if I access http://ec2-my-instanceI see the html content, but all my js and css files get error 404.

I'm kinda lost and I don't know what I'm missing to make it works, I already migrated the static content and I checked the folder which nginx is looking for the static files have them, but if I check the browser's console I see this kind of errors:

```
GET http://ec2-my-instance/static/somefile.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: Check what port your apps nginx server config is listening on, you may have connected directly to your Django app instead of going through nginx. Can you show the rest of your config?

Comment: @IainShelvington I updated to question to put the whole nginx config file

Comment: You nginx server listens on port 80, you need to make the request to that port - `http://ec2-my-instance:80` or just `http://ec2-my-instance`. Nginx handles passing the request down to the app, you shouldn't access it directly

Comment: @IainShelvington I treid it and I still don't get the static files served :(

Comment: ``DEBUG = False``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want 'alias' not 'root':

```
location /static/ {
    alias /home/ubuntu/some/folder/static/;
}
```